# type T parameters in generic method arguments

Tags: java, generics

Suppose the following classes are defined:

```
class Shape { }
class Circle extends Shape {  }
class Rectangle extends Shape { }  //  1
```

You can write a generic method to draw different shapes:

```
public static <T extends Shape> void draw(T shape) { }   // 2
```

The Java compiler replaces T with Shape:

```
public static void draw(Shape shape) {  } // 3
```

My Question is, if we define directly // 3 in our class then we still be able to pass `Shape`, `Circle` and `Rectangle` reference to method at //3. Then why do we need to write // 2 generic method with type parameter `<T extends Shape>` which is untimately going to be same as //3  ?

You can refer this link with same example : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html

Comment: You quite possibly don't. That would basically make it a bad example.

Comment: You don't NEED to do method //2. Actually it is better to do method //3 as one of the purposes of inheritance is to pass many "shapes" of your inherited object. So in this case //3 makes more sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may or may not need it. You need it if your method has to deal with other objects of the type `T` that must match the type of `T extends Shape` exactly, for example:

```
public static <T extends Shape> void drawWithShadow(T shape, Class<T> shapeClass) {
    // The shadow must be the same shape as what's passed in
    T shadow = shapeClass.newInstance();
    // Set the shadow's properties to from the shape...
    shadow.draw(); // First, draw the shadow
    shape.draw();  // Now draw the shape on top of it
}
```

Above, passing `Shape` would not be enough, because we wouldn't be able to make the shadow of the exactly same type.

In case when there is no such requirement, a simple `Shape` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, you don't need a generic method.

But you can do more in a generic method than call a dynamically linked method on its arguments.

For example, you might have a generic method that accepts and returns a collection of T elements. Parameterizing it by type allows you to use it on multiple collection types.

Other examples where generic methods are useful are in this [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

Answer (score 2):

In your example, //3 is indeed the same as //2. But in other usecases, generic type may be useful:

- you want to return value from the method, of the same type as the argument
- you have 2 or more parameters and want to set restriction that they must be of the same type

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the kind of polymorphism you are using.

In the generic case you are using *parametric polymorphism*  while in the second one you are using *polymorphism by subtype*. Actually you first case uses both kind of polymorphism.

Now, they could be similar in some aspects but they are not the same. A practical example:

```
List<Shape> shapes;
List<T extends Shape> specificShapes;
```

You can see that in the first case, not having a type parameter, I can't manage a list of a specific subtype of Shape, I can only manage an eterogeneous list of shapes but I'm unable to force any specific one on it. So I don't have any compile time juice that forbids me from adding a `Triangle` and a `Rectangle` to the `shapes`.

```
class ShapeDecorator {
  private Shape shape;

  ..

  Shape get() { return shape; }
}

class ShapeDecorator<T extends Shape> {
  private T shape;

  T get() { return shape; }
}
```

Here is another example, in this case you could write a generic decorator which is able to return a type T without the need of any cast. This can be useful in many situations in which having the common ancestor as subtype is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

The main interest is that you can restrict the usage of your method to a specific type of shape in different part of the code.

At some point you may want to parametrize it to draw only `Rectangle` and in another place only `Circle` and this will be checked at compile time even if, at runtime, you will pass something of type `Shape`